# How do I transfer items to other party members in Worlds of Ultima: The Savage Empire?

Tags: ultima-savage-empire

I've picked up quite a few things in my wanderings while playing *Worlds of Ultima: The Savage Empire*, and now I'm at my encumbrance limit. My two companions right now (Triolo and Dokray) have plenty of space in their inventories. But I can't figure out how to give stuff to them.

Clicking on items doesn't work, nor does using the "use" command. I can drop the items, but there doesn't seem to be a way to pick them up and have them end up in another character's inventory. So how do I transfer items to other party members?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. View the inventory of the person you want to move items *from*.

   - I'll assume you already know how to get to the Inventory screen. Basically you'll press **'F1'** through **'F6'** to select a party member, then either press **'Tab'** twice, or click the little bag icon under their portrait to go into their inventory. From there you can use the mouse, keyboard, or a combination of both.

**Using the mouse**

2. Click the "Move" icon at the left of the command bar. (bottom-left side of the screen)
3. Click the item you want to transfer.

   - If it's a stacked item, type the quantity to be moved.
4. Click the person *in the world view* that you want to move the item to.

**Using the keyboard**

2. Press **'M'** for Move.
3. Press **'Tab'** to move the cursor into the inventory view of the currently selected party member.
4. Use the **arrow keys** to select the item to move and press **'Enter'**.

   - If it's a stacked item, type the quantity to be moved.
5. Select the person to move the item to. Either:

   - Press the number key **'1'** through **'6'** that represents the party member. For example 1 is your player character, 2 is Triolo, and so on.
   - Use the **arrow keys** to select the person *in the world view* that you want to move the item to and press **'Enter'**. (use **'Tab'** to move the cursor back to the world view if it's in the inventory)

**Combining these commands**

At any time you can switch between the mouse and keyboard methods. For example after clicking the object to transfer with the mouse, press 2 to give it to Triolo. This game was made before modern UI standards had been developed, so the commands seem complex at first, but they become easy to do quickly after playing for a while.

Comment: Huh, I thought that "Move" meant move the character (i.e. have them walk around). And it never occurred to me to click on the character on the in the world view. I'll agree that the UI makes the commands seem complex at first! But now I know and can continue on in this game, which has been pretty engaging otherwise. Thanks!